# Retrofit - Untrusted chain even with trusted certificate

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, client-certificates

I am (sadly) putting my hands on a bad-written old Android app, it used an `HTTP` WebService which now has been translated to `HTTPS` signed with a trusted certificate by DigiCert (I checked it's validity on https://www.digicert.com/help/).

For my mental sanity, I introduced in the project Retrofit with RxJava2 for making calls to the WebService, is a copy-paste I use for other projects and always works, so I think the issue is not on my code

```
private HttpManager(Context context, String baseUrl) {
    this.context = context;
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);


    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor())
            .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                Request.Builder builder1 = chain.request().newBuilder();
                builder1.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return chain.proceed(builder1.build());
            })
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    OkHttpClient client = builder.build();


    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG){
        LoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new LoggingInterceptor.Builder()
                .loggable(true)
                .request()
                .requestTag("Request")
                .response()
                .responseTag("Response")
                .build();

        builder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
    }



    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(builder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .build();
}
```

here is one endpoint, pretty simple

```
@POST("sync/login_user.php")
Single<LoginResponseModel> login(@Body LoginRequestModel requestModel);
```

and here is how I start the call

```
disposable.add(
        httpManager.service().create(LoginService.class).login(loginRequestModel)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable1 -> {
                // do things
            })
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                onLoginError(throwable);
            })
            .flatMapCompletable(responseModel -> Completable.fromAction(() -> {
                onLoginComplete(responseModel);
            }))
            .doFinally(() -> {
                // do things
            })
        .subscribe(() -> {}, e -> {})
    );
```

Allo of this results in the following error

```
------------------Untrusted chain: ----------------------
== Chain0 == 
 AuthorityKeyIdentifier:   skdjfgsldf
 SubjectKeyIdentifier:   slkfdjhsldfg
 Serial Number:   0r9c2yr
 SubjectDN:   CN=*.url.com, OU=web site, O=NOT GONNA SAY THAT, L=Nope , C=IT
 IssuerDN:   CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
 Get not before:   Thu Nov 07 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019
 Get not after:   Fri Nov 06 13:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020
 Sig ALG name:   SHA256withRSA
 Signature:   blablabla
 Public key: 71 92 fd 46 a9 d4 // and so on...
```

What I can't explain is that all of the above code works with StackExchange APIs (in `https`) in the project but does not with the needed endpoint, I can correctly reach the server on the web (Chrome, which says it has a valid certificate), with Postman, with CURL, not a single problem.

**Note**: using Java, but Kotlin is accepted too

Comment: is it shoe network security issue

Comment: I don't know how to solve it, but I know why it fails.
Basically, you app is raising an error saying that the certificate is not trusted, mostly because you need to configure the Trust Store somehow.

For example, it works in your browser, because it already have a ton of root CA  certificates imported and trusted on it, by default. I imagine that you application doesn't have anything trusted by default. So, you need to find a way to create a trust store in your app (can't help with that, sorry :( )

Comment: can you clarify OS version of device?. because latest Okhttp and Retrofit not work in api below 21.

Comment: also check your ssl support for android. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

Comment: @hess I turned out that the certificate the server was returning is a wildcard certificate that my client uses for all of their products, it throws the untrusted chain as the certificate is too generic, I ended loading the certificate locally and check it with the one returned from my requests, gonna add an answer soon

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel - I'm targeting 28, minSdk is 18 (gonna try and eventually raise it to 21). Bytheway, I found a solution, gonna add an answer soon

Comment: @CliffBurton solution?

Comment: @LuisMartin I have no time now to post a detailed answer, being synthetic you can load the certificate itself in your project's `assets` folder, then open it so you can compare it with the server certificate. Note that this is not a good solution tho